# Stream Reader Readline detect newline characters

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

I'm trying to remove any "new line" characters from each line of text in my log file.

Below is an example entry that I am reading in with a Stream Reader :-

```
<![LOG[Raising event:
[SMS_CodePage(850), SMS_LocaleID(2057)]
instance of SoftDistProgramStartedEvent
{
    AdvertisementId = "000216F6";
    ClientID = "GUID:B55C2757-CBAE-468E-B54F-46CAF2ECF68F";
    CommandLine = "\"C:\\WINNT\\system32\\cscript.exe\" /nologo Shutdown_Desktops_Overnight.vbs";
    DateTime = "20130211080211.784000+000";
    MachineName = "DWD*****";
    PackageName = "0000073C";
    ProcessID = 2516;
    ProgramName = "Shutdown Desktops Overnight";
    SiteCode = "S00";
    ThreadID = 3640;
    UserContext = "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM";
    WorkingDirectory = "C:\\WINNT\\system32\\CCM\\Cache\\0000073C.1.System\\";
};
]LOG]!><time="08:02:11.800+000" date="02-11-2013" component="execmgr" context="" type="1" thread="3640" file="event.cpp:522">
```

In the actual Logfile this is displayed as one line in the file, with the "New Line Characters" replaced with a square.

I'm using the following code to read in the log entries :-

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Documents and Settings\riversd\Desktop\Logfile2.log"))
        {
            string Line;

            while ((Line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

            }
        }
```

The issue is that when the StreamReader reads this entry from the txt file it breaks at :-

```
"<![LOG[Raising event:"
```

I need to remove all new line characters in this entry, on the fly. I don't want to read the entire file into memory and then remove them, I'd rather deal with each log as I read it.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you could remove the newline before reading in the line, then it wouldn't be a line readable with `ReadLine` and you'd essentially be reading in the full file as one line, in the end.

Comment: I want to amend the line as i read it, on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sr.ReadLine().Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty);
```

**EDIT:**
In case the end of line is not `\r\n` but `\n` you can use regex:

```
Line = Regex.Replace(sr.ReadLine(), @"(\r\n|\n)", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Note that Environment.NewLine is `"\r\n"` for Windows, but it might be that you just want to replace `"\n"` instead.

Comment: Yeah, Ive tried this also. I wonder if can use a different Encode for the stream differently?

Comment: @Derek can you open the log file using notepad++ for example and than view->show symbol->show all characters. maybe there are some other characters? Can you also see the content of the line in debugger?

Comment: @Derek upload the file somewhere, I'll take a look at it

Comment: This doesn't work because the string returned from StreamReader.ReadLine doesn't include the new line characters.  I added an answer with a link to the MSDN doc.

Answer (score 9):

The call to Replace isn't working because of this detail from the [MSDN doc of StreamReader.ReadLine:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). **The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed**.

So if you're going to use StreamReader.ReadLine to read in the input, you could build up a new string with StringBuilder.Append (not AppendLine) as StreamReader.ReadLine implicitly removes the new line characters.

```
var filePath = "text.txt";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        sb.Append(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}

File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if anyone else was having exactly this issue.
here is the code i used to fix this issue.

```
      using (System.IO.FileStream File = new System.IO.FileStream(e.FullPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(File, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    String CompleteData = Reader.ReadToEnd();
                    foreach (String Line in CompleteData.Split(new char[] { (char)13 }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        if (Line.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Contains("Raising event"))
                        {
                             //Do Stuff
                        }
                    }
                    Reader.Close();
                }
                File.Close();
            }
```

For some reason i had to do this because just using streamreader would throw an exception saying that the file is in use from another process.

It might help someone else at a later date..