# Why does FileStream sometimes ignore invisible characters?

Tags: c#, filestream

I have two blocks of code that I've tried using for reading data out of a file-stream in C#. My overall goal here is to try and read each line of text into a list of strings, but they are all being read into a single string (when opened with read+write access *together*)...

I am noticing that the first block of code correctly reads in all of my carriage returns and line-feeds, and the other ignores them. I am not sure what is really going on here. I open up the streams in two different ways, but that shouldn't really matter right? Well, in any case here is the first block of code (that correctly reads-in my white-space characters):

```
StreamReader sr = null;
StreamWriter sw = null;
FileStream fs = null;
List<string> content = new List<string>();
List<string> actual = new List<string>();
string line = string.Empty;

// first, open up the file for reading
fs = File.OpenRead(path);
sr = new StreamReader(fs);

// read-in the entire file line-by-line
while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((line = sr.ReadLine())))
{
    content.Add(line);
}
sr.Close();
```

Now, here is the block of code that ignores all of the white-space characters (i.e. line-feed, carriage-return) and reads my entire file in one line.

```
StreamReader sr = null;
StreamWriter sw = null;
FileStream fs = null;
List<string> content = new List<string>();
List<string> actual = new List<string>();
string line = string.Empty;

// first, open up the file for reading/writing
fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
sr = new StreamReader(fs);

// read-in the entire file line-by-line
while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((line = sr.ReadLine())))
{
    content.Add(line);
}
sr.Close();
```

**Why does `Open` cause all data to be read as a single line, and `OpenRead` works correctly (reads data as multiple lines)?**

**UPDATE 1**

I have been asked to provide the text of the file that reproduces the problem. So here it is below (*make sure that CR+LF is at the end of each line!! I am not sure if that will get pasted here!*)

```
;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
;$$$$$$$$$                                                                $$$$$$$
;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
;
;
;
```

**UPDATE 2**

An exact block of code that reproduces the problem (using the text above for the file). In this case I am actually seeing the problem WITHOUT trying `Open` and only using `OpenRead`.

```
StreamReader sr = null;
StreamWriter sw = null;
FileStream fs = null;
List<string> content = new List<string>();
List<string> actual = new List<string>();
string line = string.Empty;

try
{
    // first, open up the file for reading/writing
    fs = File.OpenRead(path);
    sr = new StreamReader(fs);

    // read-in the entire file line-by-line
    while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((line = sr.ReadLine())))
    {
        content.Add(line);
    }
    sr.Close();

    // now, erase the contents of the file
    File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);

    // make sure that the contents of the file have been erased
    fs = File.OpenRead(path);
    sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = sr.ReadLine()))
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Failed: Could not erase the contents of the file.");
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Passed: Successfully erased the contents of the file.");
    }

    // now, attempt to over-write the contents of the file
    fs.Close();
    fs = File.OpenWrite(path);
    sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    foreach(var l in content)
    {
        sw.Write(l);
    }

    // read back the over-written contents of the file
    fs.Close();
    fs = File.OpenRead(path);
    sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((line = sr.ReadLine())))
    {
        actual.Add(line);
    }

    // make sure the contents of the file are correct
    if(content.SequenceEqual(actual))
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Passed: The contents that were over-written are correct!");
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Failed: The contents that were over-written are not correct!");
    }
}
finally
{
    // close out all the streams
    fs.Close();

    // finish-up with a message
    Trace.WriteLine("Finished running the overwrite-file test.");
}
```

Comment: FileStream doesn't ignore "invisible" characters, it doesn't care about the characters. `StreamReader` is the class that reads text and handles newlines, but it *doesn't* ignore them either. Is the file the *same* in both cases? Is the *content* the same? Can you post code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Obviously I must be having the X Y problem. Yes, I sure can, thanks for asking. Hope it will help to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with this code on .NET 4.6.2 on Windows. Both pieces of code yield the lines individually up until the first empty line, as one would expect, since both `File.Open` and `File.OpenRead` are simple wrappers around the `FileStream` constructor.

Comment: @JeroenMostert hang on, will post code that reproduces. Can you try .NET 4.5 in the meantime?

Comment: Neither 4.5 nor 4.6.2 have such a problem. This is such a basic operation that people would have noticed already. `FileStream` doesn't deal with characters at all, it simply returns *bytes*. It's StreamReader that interprets bytes as characters. Most likely, the content isn't the same, perhaps because the stream that writes the file was left open ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't really know what else to add, there isn't any more code than what I am showing here... :(

Comment: @StevieV add *code* that generates the file, then reads it and results in the error. Not the file itself. You may be using the same stream in both cases for example, or one file is UTF8 while the other is ASCII. Or anything.

Comment: It seems that one opens file in binary mode and the other in text mode. In text mode breaks after a new line, in binary mode doesn't check.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You bring up an interesting/valuable point, however that file is hand-typed. Is there any way I can change how I read the file?

Comment: No, your file contents makes no difference either, and I tested with both CR/LF endings and LF-only endings. It is almost inconceivable that any bug in the framework or JIT compiler itself could cause this behavior. Please do try it yourself with *this exact code* you posted in the question.

Comment: @mcNets Did you see/notice the difference!!?

Comment: According the result OpenRead() detects end-of-line character, but if you are reading text files, I would use text specific functions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're not specifying the `Encoding`, so it will be UTF-8 by default. Are you sure the file is in UTF-8? If it's some national non-ASCII code-page instead, the characters outside of ASCII range might be interpreted as multi-byte characters, which would break everything. Use the proper encoding when reading text files.

Comment: @mcNets there is no "binary mode" when talking about **streams**. `FileStream` just like any other stream only has methods that read bytes.  If there is any difference, it would be because of ASCII/UTF8/UNICODE differences between one file and another

Comment: @mcNets that's the *wrong* method. You mentioned a method that returns a `StreamReader`, not a Stream. The OP is asking about `Open` and `OpenRead` both of which open a FileStream.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you are on to something. How can I try different encodings when processing this file?

Comment: Your issue must be somewhere else. Is this the exact code which produces the problem, or is it boiled down? Have you used this exact code from the thread in a new project? Does it work the same way on machines set up with different locales? Does it work the same way on files made in different text editors?

Comment: You are not, by any chance, confusing `File.Open` with `File.OpenText` or suchlike which does involve `StreamReader` configuration? No matter how you open a `FileStream`, you're getting back the same data. But how you get your `StreamReader` matters a whole lot more.

Comment: @StevieV are you trying to read the *same* file after all or not? Because changing the encoding for the same file won't "fix" anything - the two streams are the *same* and the StreamReader uses the same default encoding

Comment: The [StreamReader constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) have overloads that accept an Encoding parameter. The class can also detect Unicode encodings like UTF8,UTF16 from the file's BOM (if it exists)

Comment: @JeroenMostert If I run this exact code, I don't see the problem at all. I must have messed up when I posted this. But I am still seeing the problem, and I have a block of code that reproduces the problem. Let me post that. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Okay updated, you guys will definitely see the problem now I am sure. Try it.

Comment: @StevieV, your problem is not with opening procedure, it’s in processing the text from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new file generated by

```
foreach(var l in content)
{
    sw.Write(l);
}
```

does not contain end-of-line characters because end-of-line characters are not included in `content`.

As @DaveKidder points out in [this thread over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978095/stream-reader-readline-detect-newline-characters), the [spec for StreamReader.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) specifically says that the resulting line does not include end of line.

When you do

```
while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((line = sr.ReadLine())))
{
    content.Add(line);
}
sr.Close();
```

You are losing end of line characters.

Comment: For the second time I try to read it that is true, but for the first time I read it in the example it works.

Comment: @StevieV The first time you read it, on line 15 through line 17, you are reading the file which was created with end-of-line symbols outside of your application. The second time you read it, on line 50 through line 53, you are reading the file created without end-of-line symbols by your application. This has nothing to do with reading methods, the first time you read data1, the second time you read data2, and data1 has different bytes than data2. After line 11, you can store the byte array, then do the same after line 48 and examine them, they will be different sets of bytes.