# Trying to get certain line endings when using streamreader

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get certain line endings when using streamreader in a C# app.

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllLines(string path)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path)) return null;
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    lines.Add(reader.ReadLine(@"(\r\n|\n)"));
                }
            }
            return lines.ToArray();
        }
```

you can see where I have reader.ReadLine(@"(\r\n|\n)");   If I write reader.ReadLine(); i have no issues but when I try to add line endings to it like I found online it tells me there is no overload to ReadLine.

Question: Can someone assist me with figuring out how to add certain line endings so I can successfully scan my CSV files?

Update:
So I found a way to add the line endings i was looking for and attempted it three different ways. But I'm still getting \r only one some lines. It doesn't make a lot of sense. Can anyone see any issues with the below lines of code?

```
var reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default);
//string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

////// attampt 1 - this gives the best result but is still splitting an a \r in one of the fields
//// List<string> lines = new List<string>(text.Split(new[] {"\r","\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None));

 ////// attempt 2  This worked almost identical to the option above but seemed faster.
 //var lines = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n");

//// attempt 3 - this split both \r and \n separately 
// List<string> lines = new List<string>(text.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray()));
```

any other suggestions on how to do this would be great!

Comment: Doesn't StreamReader already handle all line endings? The [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,a4ada5f765646068,references) says: "Reads a line. A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed."

Comment: To clarify are you trying to specify what you want to count as a line ending? And more particularly you are trying to replicate `ReadLine` except not allowing `\r` on its own as a line ending?

Comment: so just to explain what is going on i have a CSV file. when you put it in excel i have some lines that go to ZZ and other lines that go to AZ (not as long). the white space at the end of AZ all the way to ZZ gets added to the next line and screws everything. i assumed it was because the line endings were not correct but they are as you state above.

Comment: @chris Yes. I don't want \r on its own

Comment: Do you have a link where you found that example usage of the `ReadLine` method?  Because Microsoft [StreamReader.ReadLine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_StreamReader_ReadLine) takes no parameters.

Comment: unfortunately i closed it right before posting this and i'm not able to find it at this time. but you are correct i don't want a line ending to trigger with only \r. line endings should only be on \r\n. if you know any other ways that would be great

Comment: found the link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978095/stream-reader-readline-detect-newline-characters            this may be something different but the readline parameter is taking in line endings in this post and given how new i am at this stuff its hard for me to see a difference here

Comment: @funktail1989 I think you have misread the answer in [SO1478095](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978095/stream-reader-readline-detect-newline-characters).  The parameter `@"(\r\n|\n)"` is a regular expression for the [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_) method not for the ReadLine method.

Comment: @BlackFrog you are correct, i did misread it. Although i did fix it in one of my update examples above. it still, unfortunately, did not provide the expected result. any other insight you could provide would be cool!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to your question:

> so just to explain what is going on i have a CSV file. when you put it in excel i have some lines that go to ZZ and other lines that go to AZ (not as long). the white space at the end of AZ all the way to ZZ gets added to the next line and screws everything. i assumed it was because the line endings were not correct but they are as you state above

Try a [String.TrimEnd()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_TrimEnd_System_Char___) method call before adding the string to your list.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllLines(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path)) return null;
    var lines = new List<string>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            // add the TrimEnd call here
            lines.Add(reader.ReadLine().TrimEnd());
        }
    }
    return lines.ToArray();
}
```